# Python is there a fill specific cell value function for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is very straight forward, but I can't seem to find a simple, **non iterating through rows**, solution:

I have a column that can consist of numbers A,B,C,P, and Z. I want to change all "P"s to "Z"s.

just like `df['column'].fillna(0)` will fill all missing values with the 0 equivalent to the `dtype`, I was wondering what the equivalent of `df['column'].fill("P","Z")` would be. How can I achieve this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `replace`?

```
>>> df = DataFrame({'column': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'P', 'Z']})
>>> df['column'].replace('P', 'Z')
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    Z
4    Z
```